# Command not found when using system process

Tags: c#, bash, process

When I use Terminal/Bash to call an Image Magick command such as "convert" my command succeeds fine. If I use a system process from a C# script to pass arguments to the Bash console using the same command "convert" it will return with an error command not found via StandardRedirectError.

Why is the command not found when using a system process? e.g

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash");
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = installFolder;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;


    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start(); 

    if (process != null) {

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("convert"); //error: command not found
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("echo \"hello world\""); //output: "hello world"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post a more complete code sample, you need to tell Process what executable to run and pass in the arguments. [See the MSDN docs and Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Soimething like

```
   Process process = new Process();
   startInfo.Arguments = "image_[0-9].gif  image_[1-9][0-9].gif  animation.gif" 
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   process.Start("convert.exe");
```

Comment: Thats the more simple method where you call the application or script with arguments, I've already passed that hurdle. I'm using the StandardInput.WriteLine() method to pass arguments to the bash console until the process quits/exits. I will update my code anyway to make it clearer. ;)

Comment: Looking at your updated question - is convert in the required path? What if you fully qualify it @"C:\myfolder\convert.exe"?

Comment: The "convert" line is a Image Magick command line command, on it's own it brings up the help info. Image Magick is setup as an environment path as far as I'm aware due to fact I can call it via Terminal or /bin/bash manually. It is this that is causing me the confusion, as passing in the command with or without full arguments fails yet a simple echo succeeds. I will try and find it's exact path on my system and see if that helps. It can be installed in many places on systems and using a absolute path is not ideal for the tool I'm creating. Thx, input appreciated.

Comment: It seems I installed the package with Mac Ports which has a environment path in my .bash_profile. Possibly this breaks the command via system process. export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH" - something to go on anyway.

Comment: Check here too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal

Comment: That's it - good man! I've not quite fixed it but login shell is off after checking with "shopt login_shell" command. This should be enough for me to resolve it. I shall update the question with full solution asap.

Comment: Voted and cheers. Up vote the question. Loading the bash profile did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As kindly directed in the right direction by @MurrayFoxcroft this is due to the non login shell mode meaning my .bash_profile was not loaded. Do it like so:

```
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine (". ~/.bash_profile");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("convert");
```